# How to attach preventDefault() and function to physical back button on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I would like to display a slide-down menu (containing all links) when the back button is pressed. There are only 5 pages and each page is a div called by javascript which makes the back button useless without the requested modification.

How do I call my custom functions from the back button using jQuery?

Thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [jQuery BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)?

Comment: Thanks Dan but BBQ clearly isn't what I'm looking for (run only a custom function from the back button)

Comment: What you're looking for will never work. You can't attach a handler to the back button because the back button is not part of the DOM, it is part of the browser's chrome. What you probably want to do is enable functionality so that when the back button is clicked, it goes back to the 'page' (the div) which the user was last looking at. This is where the BBQ plugin can (and will) help you. To show a drop-down menu linking to each 'page' of the site, you can just add that to the page somewhere...

Comment: Dan : you're totally right. I didn't see the pros of using BBQ first but after a second thought it was exactly what I was looking for in the end. Everything works fine now since I've implemented it. Thanks a lot for that. You helped me a lot :) Cheers